# Cannot seem to regexp extract a word on URL (Data Studio)

Tags: regex, looker-studio, regular-language

I read from somewhere that Datastudio use little bit different Regular Expression from other places: that it uses RE2. I, however, manage to find a site to test for RE2 regex and able to get it running, but it was not working on Data studio.

I have this URL I wanted to extract:

```
/marketing/news-717777

/finance/news-123456?asdasdasd_asdad
```

I wanted the regex to extract the word with dash and number. "news-******".
The result would be like this

```
news-717777
news-123456
```

I cannot seem to get it to work on data studio. The code that I have tried are the following:

```
(news-).*(?=\?)|(news-).*
(news-).*(?=\\?)|(news-).*
(news-.*?)\?
(news-.*).*(?=\?)
```

The closest I get is to get news with number"news-***", but I cannot remove the "?" that comes after. Anyone has any ideas on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several solutions here.

*Solution 1*: matching digits after a specific string (here, `news-`)

```
(news-[0-9]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLljY5/1), `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits.

*Solution 2*: If there can be any char other than `?` after `news-`, if there can be chars other than digits, you can use

```
(news-[^?]+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLljY5/2), where `[^?]+` matches one or more chars other than a `?` char.